# Does assigning visualforce page to object buttons override the OWD

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, security, button, owd

I have Opportunity OWD set to Private.

Have over ridden the NEW,EDit,View and Clone buttons of Opportunity with VF page.

I created opp record with USER1.

Logged in as USER2 and still able to see the Opp record(which is a VF page).

Does assigning VF page to buttons violate the OWD..??

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Is there a custom controller behind the page? If so, you sure it has "with sharing" in it's declaration?

Comment: Hey, I have Opp OWD set to private. i am sending an email on Opp creation to certain set of Users.   Say user1 created Opp and mail is sent to User1,user2,User3. I want all 3 users to be able to view the record when clicked on link.

Answer (score 2):

**Objects and field access:**

A visual force page will enforce FLS and CRUD if the fields are binded as sObject fields using input/outputField.

Example: If a user does not have write permission for a field, that field will be shown as read only in edit mode in VF page.

**Record Access:**

A visual force page does not enforces OWD or record level access, that is the job of the controller.

If you are using a custom controller without sharing model, Record level access will not be enforced however FLS and CRUD will be enforced if you use inputField and outputField.

Please refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS) for more details